# GraphViz binary tree left and right child

Tags: binary-tree, graphviz, binary-search-tree

i'm trying to draw binary tree using GraphViz but i have problems about left child and right child. There is a way to force a node to be right or left child?
This is my sample code:

```
digraph G{
5 -> 3;
5 -> 8;
3 -> 1;
3 -> 4;
8 -> 6;
8 -> 12;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This should do it. `ordering=out` means the nodes should stay in order specified in the input.

```
digraph G{
  graph [ordering="out"];
  5 -> 3;
  5 -> 8;
  3 -> 1;
  3 -> 4;
  8 -> 6;
  8 -> 12;
}
```